# Expresso Store: Grab the shipping rule description based on chosen shipping method

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, devdemon

In Store, when you set up a Shipping Rule, there's a Description field that our client would like to take advantage of. However, I'm not seeing a tag (or some other way) to display the text that is in that description field.

Screenshot:
[image]

Basically, we want to show the contents of the Description field based on what the user has chosen for their Shipping Method.

Not sure how to do that. Could use another set of eyes on this. Thanks!

Using Store 2.5.1, EE 2.10.1.

Comment: Welp, guess this isn't possible. Per the docs:
"You may also add a description of each rule (for your own internal use - not displayed to customers)..."

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modifying the store module itself you can do the following (for Store v 2.5.1)

In file \system\expressionengine\third_party\store\src\Service\ShippingService.php line 139, in function `get_order_shipping_methods` > `foreach ($methods as $method)` >  `if ($rule) {` add line

```
    $option->rule_description = $rule->name;
```

In file \system\expressionengine\third_party\store\src\Model\OrderShippingMethod.php line 53, in function `toTagArray` add line

```
    $attributes['rule_description'] = $this->rule_description;
```

In file system\expressionengine\third_party\store\src\Model\ShippingRule.php line 16 in `protected $fillable = array(...` add 'name' string to array so line looks like:

```
    'percent_rate', 'min_rate', 'max_rate', 'enabled', 'name');
```

Then add `{rule_description}` to your `{shipping_methods}` tag. Example:

```
    {shipping_methods}
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" class="shipping-methods" value="{method_id}" id="shipping-method-{method_id}" {if method_selected}checked{/if} />
    <label  for="shipping-method-{method_id}">{method_title} {method_price} <em>{rule_description}</em></label>
    </li>
    {/shipping_methods}
```